# Identify unique values within a multivariable subset

Tags: r

I have data that look like these:

```
Subject Site Date
1 2 '2020-01-01'
1 2 '2020-01-01'
1 2 '2020-01-02'
2 1 '2020-01-02'
2 1 '2020-01-03'
2 1 '2020-01-03'
```

And I'd like to create an order variable for unique dates by Subject and Site. i.e.

```
Want
1
1
2
1
2
2
```

I define a little wrapper:

`rle <- function(x) cumsum(!duplicated(x))`

and I notice inconsistent behavior when I supply:

`have1 <- unlist(tapply(val$Date, val[, c( 'Site', 'Subject')], rle))`

versus

`have2 <- unlist(tapply(val$Date, val[, c('Subject', 'Site')], rle))`

```
> have1
[1] 1 1 2 1 2 2
> have2
[1] 1 2 2 1 1 2
```

Is there any way to ensure that the natural ordering of the dataset is followed regardless of the specific columns supplied to the `INDEX` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
val %>% 
   group_by(Subject, Site) %>%
   mutate(Want = match(Date, unique(Date))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Subject  Site Date        Want
    <int> <int> <chr>      <int>
1       1     2 2020-01-01     1
2       1     2 2020-01-01     1
3       1     2 2020-01-02     2
4       2     1 2020-01-02     1
5       2     1 2020-01-03     2
6       2     1 2020-01-03     2
```

---

```
val$Want <- with(val, ave(as.integer(as.Date(Date)), Subject, Site,
     FUN = \(x) match(x, unique(x))))
val$Want
[1] 1 1 2 1 2 2
```

#### data

```
val <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Site = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", 
"2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```